# Does PostSharp add code during precompilation of assembly?

Tags: postsharp

When assembly using PostSharp [Log] aspect was decompiled, the decompiled code appeared without new code added to it. Doesn't PostSharp add code corresponding to aspect during precompilation?

Answer (score 0):

PostSharp post-processes the compiler output by reading and disassembling the intermediate assembly, execute the required transformations and validations, and rewriting the final assembly to disk.

PostSharp integrates itself in the build process via PostSharp.targets. NuGet adds the PostSharp.targets import to your project when you install PostSharp nuget package.

Let's consider this method:

`[Log]
public void Method() { }`

If everything works correctly then the decompiled C# code of this method starts like this (PostSharp 5.0):

`public void Method()
{
    bool flag = <>z__Program.DefaultCategory.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug);
    LogMemberInfo logMemberInfo;`

If you don't see this code, it may indicate that PostSharp is not correctly installed to your project or it is not correctly configured.

[Adding Detailed Logging to your Solution](http://doc.postsharp.net/add-logging) article explains how to correctly configure and add PostSharp to your project.